# Regex to mm:ss limited to 60 minutes

Tags: regex

I need a regex that must accept minutes and seconds with pattern mm:ss.
But if I have 60 minutes, then the seconds must be 00.

I have this expression, that resolve the format, but not limit in cases like above.

`^([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])$`

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the case you want to match:

```
^((?:60:00)|(?:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]))$
```

Comment: I agree, though OP put the values in group (presumably so he can create ints from them).

Comment: `^([0-5][0-9]|60):([0-5][0-9])$` assuming 00:00 will be also accepted

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks